# How to select all empty p tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I select all the empty tag using jQuery.

I want to select

```
<p></p>
<p style="display: block"></p>
<p> </p>
<p>     </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

and not

```
<p>0</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select all the empty tag using jQuery.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436985/how-can-i-select-all-the-empty-tag-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var t = $('p').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vV8uQ/)

Answer (score 0):

use :empty selector [:empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```
if ($('p').is(':empty')){
  //do something
}
```

or if you want all empty P tags

```
$('p:empty').each(function(){
  // do something with empty Paragraphs
});
```

Comment: will it work with `&nbsp` and ` ` ?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('p:empty')
```

as your selector