# How can I select all the empty tag using jQuery.?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I select all the empty tag using jQuery.

I want to select

```
<p></p>
<p style="display: block"></p>
<p> </p>
<p>     </p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

and not

```
<p>0</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

I tried with `:empty` but it is not working with my options. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the example with the `:empty` you have tried?

Comment: they are actually not empty. spaces are there

Comment: @Ravi: My apologies, I accidently posted it two time. what should I do next ?

Comment: @blessed Mod will close the question soon.. dont worry.. but do consider searching before you post the question

Comment: @Ravi: Both questions are asked by me .. almost at same time

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using `jQuery.filter()`.

```
var empty_p = $('p').filter(function(){
   return !$.trim($(this).text());
}).get();
```

Comment: Will this return elements containing only spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**jQuery filter**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('p').filter(function () {
   return !$(this).text().trim();
});
```

Comment: That's not how you use [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Comment: @koala_dev this is not a jQuery trim. [String.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Oops, right, sorry for the confusion

Comment: String.trim() will not work with `IE`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").each(function(index){
        var html = $(this).html();
        html = filter(html, " ");
        html = filter(html, "&nbsp;");

        if ($(this).html() == ""){
            //YOUR CODE
        }
    });
});

function filter(string, char){
    while(string.indexOf(char) > 0){
        string.replace(char, "");
    }
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/seano666/Yaq2w/)

Comment: Will fail for whitespace and `&nbsp;`

Comment: Ah, always helps to read the question I suppose  I've made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) methods.
Here's a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/snqSw/

```
$("p").filter(function(){
        $(this).text($.trim($(this).text())==""?"Works":$(this).text());
                            });
```

Answer (score -1):

One more way to do this, using regexps instead of `trim()`:

```
$('p').filter(function () {
    return !/\S/.test( $(this).text() );
})
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMeR5/))

Note that this (and all the other solution based on `$(this).text()`) will also match e.g. this paragraph:

```
<p><a href="http://example.com">&nbsp;</a></p>
```

or even:

```
<p><img src="http://example.com/image.gif"></p>
```

Depending on what you want to do with the paragraphs, this might or might not be what you want.  If it isn't, you're going to need something a bit more complicated; the details will depend on just what, exactly, you'd like to consider an "empty" paragraph.